# How to fix EFI shell when install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, uefi

I have 2 days trying to install Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20 in dual boot. I researched and found that windows should be installed first and then Linux.

I already have Windows 10 installed in BIOS mode = UEFI.

I have BIOS with UEFI enabled.

I created a bootable USB using Rufus from an Ubuntu iso file with the following parameters

- GPT and UEFI (non CSM)
- FAT32.

Now, when I try to boot from bootable USB, appears a yellow shell that I found is named EFI shell and I'm stuck in how to fix this.

Note: In case it matters, the motherboard is American Megatrends a kind of old.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried following this guide to open grub from the EFI shell? https://askubuntu.com/questions/981267/how-to-install-ubuntu-using-the-efi-shell

Comment: Directly dd the iso using Rufus and then try

Comment: @Madhubala hi, what do you mean with directly dd the iso?

Comment: As I understand (and this may be incorrect) the USB you have created should contain all the necessary files to install the system, but somehow it's made to boot into the EFI shell instead of just grub to load the GUI installation guide. @Madhubalas suggestion to dd the iso is to make a new USB install medium that would work 'as is'. But, if the assumption is correct that all the files are there, the method in my link would simply load GRUB and you can proceed with the install as normal (and yes, you will be able to choose between Windows and Ubuntu at startup).

Comment: @glaux Yes, your assumption is correct. I had to reinstall windows because I saw somewhere that EFI shell appears when windows is installed in BIOS mode =Legacy. Then I reinstall windows with BIOS mode = UEFI and the EFI shell remains. So, the reason for EFI shell was other. Then, I think I'll try the info in link you share. I hope not to make a mess, since I haven't found a step by step guide or video to install Ubuntu after windows when this EFI shell appears. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hmm, at that point I’d try recreating the Ubuntu USB installer. Maybe try Etcher https://www.balena.io/etcher/ instead of Rufus just to try something different.

Comment: @glaux I've just tried to make a bootable USB with Rufus using a Puppy Linux iso named `bionicpup64-8.0-uefi.iso` with parameters GPT, EUFI and FAT32 and I got the installation menu of Puppy Linux. Then I tried to do the same process with the Ubuntu iso `ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` but with Ubuntu bootable USB boots directly on Windows10. What could be different between puppy Linux iso and Ubuntu iso?

Comment: @GerCas It sounds like the .iso is corrupted in some way, if possible try redownloading. Have you checked the sha256 checksum of your current .iso file? Could be interesting to know if that check fails, then you definitely have your answer. https://www.incredigeek.com/home/verify-ubuntu-iso-on-windows/ or https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview.

Comment: @glaux Hi again. Yes, I checked using what ubuntu site suggests and the answer is OK. `echo "b45165ed3cd437b9ffad02a2aad22a4ddc69162470e2622982889ce5826f6e3d *ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso" | shasum -a 256 --check` but when I try to flash with balenaEtcher, when finishes shows message saying checksum is wrong but I'm confused how the above command is OK. I'll try to download via torrent as almost final attempt :(